Box around nodes to account for the label of each nodes tikzpicture
The problem
I am drawing boxes outside of labelled nodes and the boxes does not account for the labels above the inner nodes.
Here is the MWE of my document:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{new@fontshape}{anything}

\usepackage[russian,indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage{newtx}

\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, chains, decorations.pathreplacing, positioning, fit}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T2A}{\familydefault}{Tempora-TLF}%
}

\primebars
\let\emptyset\varnothing

\geometry{
 a4paper,
 margin=3cm
 }

\newcommand{\?}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}
\noautomath


\begin{document}

\vspace{5mm}
\section*{Hubungan sintaksis}
\vspace{5mm}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2.5cm, text centered, draw=black, text width=3cm]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, text width=2.5cm]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\def\layersep{2.5cm}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm, box/.style = {draw,black,inner sep=10pt,rounded corners=5pt}]
  \node (kr) [process, label=above:{Agen}] {Kerusiaan};
  \node (bn) [process, right of=kr, label=above:{Sasaran}] {Binan};

  \path [line] (kr) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above,align=center ] {Aksi} (bn);

  \node[box,fit=(kr)(bn)] {};

\end{tikzpicture}\hspace{1cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm, box/.style = {draw,black,inner sep=10pt,rounded corners=5pt}]
  \node (kr) [process, label=above:{Agen}] {Binan};
  \node (bn) [process, right of=kr, label=above:{Sasaran}] {Non-kerusiaan};

  \path [line] (kr) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above,align=center ] {Aksi} (bn);

  \node[box,fit=(kr)(bn)] {};

\end{tikzpicture}\hspace{1cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm, box/.style = {draw,black,inner sep=10pt,rounded corners=5pt}]
  \node (kr) [process, label=above:{Agen}] {Binan};
  \node (bn) [process, right of=kr, label=above:{Sasaran}] {Kerusiaan};

  \path [line] (kr) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above,align=center ] {Aksi} (bn);

  \node[box,fit=(kr)(bn)] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}

Here is the typeset of the code:

The box just ignore that the labels are part of each nodes; it just goes through it and does not leave space above the labels.
I want so that the boxes do not go through the labels, with an added texts above them. Approximately like this:

How can I improve my code?

What I have done so far
I know I can just change the sep in {draw,black,inner sep=10pt,rounded corners=5pt}, but it creates an uneven spaces between the upper and lower box space:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{new@fontshape}{anything}

\usepackage[russian,indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage{newtx}

\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, chains, decorations.pathreplacing, positioning, fit}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T2A}{\familydefault}{Tempora-TLF}%
}

\primebars
\let\emptyset\varnothing

\geometry{
 a4paper,
 margin=3cm
 }

\newcommand{\?}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}
\noautomath


\begin{document}

\vspace{5mm}
\section*{Hubungan sintaksis}
\vspace{5mm}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2.5cm, text centered, draw=black, text width=3cm]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, text width=2.5cm]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\def\layersep{2.5cm}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm, box/.style = {draw,black,inner sep=18pt,rounded corners=5pt}]
  \node (kr) [process, label=above:{Agen}] {Kerusiaan};
  \node (bn) [process, right of=kr, label=above:{Sasaran}] {Binan};

  \path [line] (kr) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above,align=center ] {Aksi} (bn);

  \node[box,fit=(kr)(bn)] {};

\end{tikzpicture}\hspace{1cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm, box/.style = {draw,black,inner sep=18pt,rounded corners=5pt}]
  \node (kr) [process, label=above:{Agen}] {Binan};
  \node (bn) [process, right of=kr, label=above:{Sasaran}] {Non-kerusiaan};

  \path [line] (kr) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above,align=center ] {Aksi} (bn);

  \node[box,fit=(kr)(bn)] {};

\end{tikzpicture}\hspace{1cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm, box/.style = {draw,black,inner sep=18pt,rounded corners=5pt}]
  \node (kr) [process, label=above:{Agen}] {Binan};
  \node (bn) [process, right of=kr, label=above:{Sasaran}] {Kerusiaan};

  \path [line] (kr) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above,align=center ] {Aksi} (bn);

  \node[box,fit=(kr)(bn)] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}


I want it so that the space between the upper box from the labels and the lower box from the bottom of the nodes are equal. With added texts above the outer box. What should I do?

You will have to give the labels a name as well (they're also just nodes) and then use those names with the fit key as well. Alternatively, you could use the bounding box as the fit value since your fit boxes include the whole diagram. TikZ provides a backgrounds library for this.

Hello, I tried \node (kr_n) [above of=kr, yshift=-3.2cm] {Agen} and \node (bn_n) [above of=bn, yshift=-3.2cm] {Sasaran} but they seem to give even larger space on top of the kr_n and bn_n nodes.

I made it work through this code:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{new@fontshape}{anything}

\usepackage[russian,indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage{newtx}

\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, chains, decorations.pathreplacing, positioning, fit}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T2A}{\familydefault}{Tempora-TLF}%
}

\primebars
\let\emptyset\varnothing

\geometry{
 a4paper,
 margin=3cm
 }

\newcommand{\?}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}
\noautomath


\begin{document}

\vspace{5mm}
\section*{Hubungan sintaksis}
\vspace{5mm}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2.5cm, text centered, draw=black, text width=3cm]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, text width=2.5cm]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\def\layersep{2.5cm}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm, box/.style = {draw,black,inner sep=5pt,rounded corners=5pt}]
  \node (kr) [process, fill=gray!15,thin,rounded corners] {Kerusiaan};
  \node (bn) [process, fill=gray!60,thin,rounded corners, right of=kr] {Binan};
  \node (n1) [inner sep=0pt,draw=none,above=2pt of kr] {Agen};
  \node (n2) [inner sep=0pt,draw=none,above=3.5pt of bn] {Sasaran};

  \path [line] (kr) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above,align=center] {Aksi} (bn);
  \path (kr) -- node[midway,draw=none,inner sep=2pt, above=12.5mm] {teks} (bn);

  \node[box,fit=(kr)(bn)(n1)(n2)] {};

\end{tikzpicture}\hspace{1cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm, box/.style = {draw,black,inner sep=5pt,rounded corners=5pt}]
  \node (kr) [process, fill=gray!60,thin,rounded corners] {Binan};
  \node (bn) [process, fill=gray!5,draw,dashed, right of=kr] {Non-kerusiaan};
  \node (n1) [inner sep=0pt,draw=none,above=2pt of kr] {Agen};
  \node (n2) [inner sep=0pt,draw=none,above=3.5pt of bn] {Sasaran};

  \path [line] (kr) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above,align=center ] {Aksi} (bn);
  \path (kr) -- node[midway,draw=none,inner sep=2pt, above=12.5mm] {teks} (bn);

  \node[box,fit=(kr)(bn)(n1)(n2)] {};

\end{tikzpicture}\hspace{1cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm, box/.style = {draw,black,inner sep=5pt,rounded corners=5pt}]
  \node (kr) [process, fill=gray!60,thin,rounded corners] {Binan};
  \node (bn) [process, fill=gray!15,thin,rounded corners, right of=kr] {Kerusiaan};
  \node (n1) [inner sep=0pt,draw=none,above=2pt of kr] {Agen};
  \node (n2) [inner sep=0pt,draw=none,above=3.5pt of bn] {Sasaran};

  \path [line] (kr) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above,align=center ] {Aksi} (bn);
  \path (kr) -- node[midway,draw=none,inner sep=2pt, above=12.5mm] {teks} (bn);

  \node[box,fit=(kr)(bn)(n1)(n2)] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}

Resulting in this:

Another suggestions are welcome!

Instead of creating three tikzpicture environments, I create just one in which each of your 3 figures is in a scope environment, allowing you to position them precisely in relation to each other.
I then name each label Agen as soon as it is defined.
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{new@fontshape}{anything}

\usepackage[russian,indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage{newtx}

\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, chains, decorations.pathreplacing, positioning, fit}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T2A}{\familydefault}{Tempora-TLF}%
}

\primebars
\let\emptyset\varnothing

\geometry{
 a4paper,
 margin=3cm
 }

\newcommand{\?}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}
\noautomath


\begin{document}

\vspace{5mm}
\section*{Hubungan sintaksis}
\vspace{5mm}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2.5cm, text centered, draw=black, text width=3cm]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, text width=2.5cm]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\def\layersep{2.5cm}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm, box/.style = {draw,black,inner sep=5pt,rounded corners=5pt}]
  \node (kr) [process, label={[name=label 1]above:Agen}] {Kerusiaan};
  \node (bn) [process, right of=kr, label=above:Sasaran] {Binan};

  \path [line] (kr) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above,align=center ] {Aksi} (bn);

  \node[fit=(bn)(label 1),inner sep=0pt] (fit 1){};
  \node[box,fit=(kr)(fit 1)] {};
    
\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
  \node (kr) [process, label={[name=label 2]above:Agen}] {Binan};
  \node (bn) [process, right of=kr, label=above:{Sasaran}] {Non-kerusiaan};

  \path [line] (kr) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above,align=center ] {Aksi} (bn);
  \node[fit=(bn)(label 2),inner sep=0pt] (fit 2){};
  \node[box,fit=(kr)(fit 2)] {};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=16cm]
  \node (kr) [process, label={[name=label 3]above:Agen}] {Binan};
  \node (bn) [process, right of=kr, label=above:{Sasaran}] {Kerusiaan};

  \path [line] (kr) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above,align=center ] {Aksi} (bn);
  \node[fit=(bn)(label 3),inner sep=0pt] (fit 3){};
  \node[box,fit=(kr)(fit 3)] {};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}



Thanks for your suggestion! Is there any ways to make sure that the space above is as tight as the space above? Would be nicer if the box wrap right not too far from the Agen and Sasaran

By tracing the box around Agen, you can visualize the spaces surrounding each node to find the parameters that suit you best. Here, I'm imposing a depth on the Agen label text.  \node (kr) [process, label={[name=label 1,draw,text depth=6pt,inner sep=0pt]above:Agen}] {Kerusiaan};

Nice! It also works :)
